# is it good practice to use custom tag lib to generate html forms dynamically?

Tags: model-view-controller, custom-tags

I'm using MVC architecture, I have used my own custom taglib along with JSTL that will generate forms, gridList  dynamically. is it a proper practice to do it. is it make any impact on performance?

```
<c:forEach items="${uiFieldList}" var="u" >
 <div class="span5"> 
    <div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" ><spring:message code="${u.fieldLabel}" /><c:if test="${u.mandatory =='Y'}"><strong style="color:red;">*</strong></c:if></label>
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="input-prepend">
      <iana:text name="${u.name}" id="${u.id}" value="${u.value}" ></iana:text>
    </div>

      </div>
  </div>    
 </div>
```

Any suggestions?